# ¿como "Linkear" una imagen en HTML?

Tags: html

Estoy iniciando en HTML y requiero que al dar clic en una imagen me redireccione a otra pagina. ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?
Este es el codigo:

```
<img href="#" src="image/circle-hombre.png" width="240" height="240" alt="">
```

tenia entendido que en el href="" en medio de las comillas va la dirección de la pagina a la cual quiero redireccionar, pero no me da.

Gracias.

Comment: en el href va la url , de esta manera lo hice yo    `<a href="google.com"><img src="image/circle-hombre.png" alt="logo telegram"/></a>`

Comment: `href` no es un atributo del elemento `img`. Debes usar un `a` conjuntamente.

Comment: No te funciona por que la etiqueta img no posee como atributo un `href` https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-img-element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos a mencionar 2 puntos importantes:

- La etiqueta [**`img`**](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) no posee un *atributo* `href` dado lo cual no puedes implementarlo ahi.
- En cambio como puedes leer [una etiqueta **`a`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) si posee o puede tener un [atributo href](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element)

**Comentarios**

- Quedando entonces la imagen contenida dentro de la etiqueta anchor  y esta última tendrá el enlace
- Lo anterior es válido, pues [los elementos en línea pueden contener a otros elementos en línea](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements)